# Regular expression to match “select…from” sql queries

Tags: ruby, regex, expression

```
str = "SELECT\r\n  money\r\nFROM\r\n  accounts"
```

i want to transfrom str to

`"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts"` using ruby Regular expression.

thank you for help

Comment: Please show more sample data.

Comment: a = "SELECT\r\n  device_id\r\nFROM\r\n  temp.test_sets  AS device_infos\r\nJOIN (\r\n  SELECT\r\n    google_ad_id\r\n  FROM\r\n    `test*`\r\n)

Comment: "SELECT COUNT(*)   FROM\r\n     device_id\r\nFROM\r\n  temp.test_Set_20180101"

Comment: i just want  string between SELECT and FROM

Comment: Please take a tour of the site and read about how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that: ( [run here](https://ideone.com/Fe0fVf) )

```
re = /(select).*?(from)[\\r\\n]*/i
str = 'SELECT\\r\\n money\\r\\nFROM\\r\\n accounts'
subst = '\\1 count(*) \\2'

result = str.gsub(re, subst)

# Print the result of the substitution
puts result
```

moreover if you want to get anything between select and from then just put in a capture group to the above regex:

```
(select)(.*?)(from)[\\r\\n]*
```

here `(.*?)` is capture group 2 which contains your contents between selet-from.

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R7N0k2/2)